# SQL DB scheme modeling: Vehicle with two different type owners

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm modeling MySQL database and started struggling.

Situation: There is `vehicle` table about all it's parameters. There is `person` table with people info. And also there is `firm` table with firm info. Every person and every firm can have 0..* vehicles. Every vehicle can have 0..1 owner. Vehicle owner can be only one person OR firm at once.

So I am going to query using vehicleid to get info about owner. Because there is two kind of owner in different tables, what should I do ? Add column to vehicle table which says which type owner is ?

Of course, I'm planning to create additional relation table. But I don't know how to deal with problem then foreign key can refence to two different table and only to one row.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Create a table "owner" with ID, companyID, personID so you get either NULL or a valid and unique foreign key relation for each of the related tables.

Comment: But then there will be NULL value in 50% row in those two columns

Comment: That is right. But that is by far preferable over one columns referencing multiple tables.
What You also could do is have a central Id table (which I do all the time) then reference that from the vehecle table and later ask if the respective ID exists in person or company table. But that makes for far less effecient queries than to simply cut out the NULLs from your (implicit) temp table.

Comment: Hmm... What about creating 2 relation tables: p_owners, f_owners. Add to vehicle owner type. So then I query I look to owner type and then looking to right relation table and then by relation table I could find owners info ?

Comment: Well what is distinguishing a Company from a person is basically a Companyname (and maybe a VAT number) so maybe you assign ownership to a contact which either has a company name or not.

Comment: Are you able to make changes to existing tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to have as you said a third column that would point you towards the right type of owner for each case, or you could have the person id or firm id to start with X value, such as a firm starting with F then the actual id , F0001. Then you could query with a LIKE 'F%'which would bring all values that  start with F. Take it with a grain of salt tho, I still have much to learn.